# Conditional IF statement in a PHP Doctrine 1.2 SET statement

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I would like find the correct syntax for the SET line:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('Media m')
->set('m.fallback IF(m.id = ?, 1, 0)', $id)  <-- not correct
->execute();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I dont think update supports that... actually update doesnt support much more than simple where clauses, You mahve to resort to RawSql or using PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that could be done with two queries:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('Media m')
    ->set('m.fallback', 1)
    ->where('m.id = ?', $id)
    ->execute();

Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('Media m')
    ->set('m.fallback', 0)
    ->where('m.id != ?', $id)
    ->execute();
```

I don't know if it suits you, but at least that will do what you want. May not work *out of the box*, as I don't have Doctrine 1.2 at hand, so can't test this. But I think the idea is clear :)

Comment: Thanks. I pretty much used something like that - was hoping for a cool one liner :)