# Doctrine 1.2 Control Flow Function "IF"

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Using Doctrine 1.2.4,
i cant't resolve using "IF" MySQL instruction under Doctrine.

I want generate this SQL code :

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytable.state = IF(mytable.state=0, 128, mytable.state)
```

But using :

```
$stmt_update = Doctrine_Query::create()
->update('Mytable mytable')
->set('mytable.state', 'IF(mytable.state=0, 128, mytable.state)')
->execute();
```

Result under mysql server is :
mytable.state = IF(mytable.state)

```
$stmt_update>getDql(); // 'UPDATE Mytable mytable SET mytable.state = IF(mytable.state=0, 128, mytable.state )'
$stmt_update->getSqlQuery(); // 'UPDATE mytable SET  mytable.state = IF(mytable.state)'
```

getSqlQuery() method is used to call Mysql, but with incorrect statement SQL.

Is a way to using IF with Doctrine 1.x ?

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/3faa518645e32eda%23&usg=AFQjCNEuqznC25z1EAzF4NIcfln8VG_Brg
This is not supported by DQL currently.

Is a an extension available for IF with Doctrine 1 ? (like DoctrineExtensions / lib /
DoctrineExtensions / Query / Mysql / IfElse.php )
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/IfElse.php

[Conditional IF statement in a PHP Doctrine 1.2 SET statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780026/conditional-if-statement-in-a-php-doctrine-1-2-set-statement) is not usable.

Answer (score 2):

Just put space between `IF` and `(` my version is 1.2.3 :

```
$stmt_update = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('Mytable mytable')
    ->set('mytable.state', 'IF (mytable.state=0, 128, mytable.state)');

echo $stmt_update->getSqlQuery();
```

I'm getting:

`UPDATE Mytable SET mytable.state = IF (mytable.state=0, 128, mytable.state)`